# primefaces dataTable style?

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces, datatable

I want to create a table using primefaces but my table column's width isn't equal for the header and body. I tried to add `style="width: inherit"` or `style="width: 30%"` for each column but the width still uneven between the table header and table body. The table will nicely uniform if it's not scroll-able but I want a scroll-able table.
Here is my code:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="1" class="plan-panel" columnClasses="label, value">
    <h:outputText class="deploy-label" value="Table 1"/>
    <p:dataTable var="service" value="aaaa"
                 id="service-table" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="250">
        <p:column headerText="Col1" width="20">
            <h:outputText value="test122222222222"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Col2" width="20">
            <h:outputText value="test255567y774"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Col3" width="20">
            <h:outputText value="test3433666"/>
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="Col4" width="20">
            <h:outputText value="test43364667"/>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>

</h:panelGrid>
```

This is how the table looks like:
[image]

I wonder if anyone knows how to apply style on this table so the table's header and body width are equal.

Thanks

Comment: PF Version? I assume an old one or did you try outside the panelgrid?

Comment: hi, my PF version is 3.5 and I did tried it outside of panelgrid but still not algin even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to make a Simple `width` in your `Column` example

```
<p:column headerText="Col2" width="20"><h:outputText value="test122222222222"/></p:column>
```

I tried to changed it like that and it worked for me , it's true that the column spice is very small but that worked for me hope that help.

Comment: Hi, I tried it width=20 for all of them but it still not align nicely

Comment: I fixed the code and the picture now shows how the table looks like using width=20

Answer (score 0):

The only 'good' answer in this case is to either stop using scrollable or to use a newer version since 3.5 is rather old (6.0 is already out). There have been lots of changes/improvements in this area.

You could try patching the CSS or most likely the js of the datatable but calculating and aligning the dynamic widths is rather cumbersome. I doubt someone is going to do that for you.

One thing you could try is to see what `table-layout: fixed` does when applied to both tables (look at the source) and then maybe give each column a fixed width like you do or maybe via css

Comment: Hi, where can i find more info on `table-layout: fixed` ?